# Chrome Web Requests getting stuck for 8 seconds

Tags: performance, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, httpwebrequest

### The Problem

In Chrome some people in our company are experiencing slowness loading some pages. I've profiled this in chrome and I can see there is a task that sits there and does nothing for ~8 seconds:

[image]

The actual request is only taking about 24ms to complete the request:

[image].

Devtools network tab reflects the same results as fiddler.
This has only started happening in the past ~1 month, and slowly more people in the company are experiencing it.

### Other Details

- Incognito mode has no effect.
- Closing all chrome windows fixes it temporarily.
- Opening a debug instance of chrome is uneffected.
- In the events on the request, there is a huge jump between load events:

  [image]
- Seems to be caused by chrome being open for a long time. I get it a lot less frequently since restarting most days.
  Any idea's on what could be causing this?

### Update

The requests taking a long time was actually just a symptom of the issue. The real issue is something causing the DOM to freeze. I've tracked it down to be the [footer functionality of Kendo](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/configuration/columns.footertemplate) grids. Without the footerTemplate being set, the grids load at their normal speed. 
We've contacted Telerik, but they haven't had any other reports of a similar issue. I've also tried removing all extensions, analytics, and anti-virus' on our computer's but no change. 
The only thing that has seemed to work is changing chrome back to an older version. So it's seemingly connected to the chrome version, and something about DOM updating.

Comment: You'll probably need to dig the internals: [tracing](https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/trace-event-profiling-tool), [logging](https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging) and `chrome://net-export`

Comment: is this a chrome only issue or does the problem persist in other browsers? Have you checked the network tab to see if a request is stalling at any point? Is the request external or internal (as I see you are using localhost) as I can't quite make it out on the screenshots.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie this problem is only an issue in chrome, all other browsers are fine. We've tried both internal and external connections and it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: the only thing I can suggest is to flush the DNS cache in the browser then, Chrome has a strange habit of sticking on a poor path to a server. I did think it was likely to be anti virus as that is a common symptom but unless your anti virus doesn't play well with Chrome for some reason that doesn't appear to be the cause.

Answer (score 2):

There could be two issues as per your explanation and the screenshot you have posted here.

> First, there could be some issue with **google-analytics** loading.

For performance boost on modern browsers, google has suggested to use **Alternative Async Tag**.

```
<!-- Google Analytics -->
<script>
window.ga=window.ga||function(){(ga.q=ga.q||[]).push(arguments)};ga.l=+new Date;
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
<script async src='https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js'></script>
<!-- End Google Analytics -->
```

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/#alternative_async_tag

I would recommend you to put this tag at the bottom just before the `</body>` tag for maximum performance.

> Second, there could be some issue with firewall.

Please check with your network administrator if there are any request blocking.